# Reading large files using mapreduce in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I have a code that reads files from FTP server and writes it into `HDFS`. I have implemented a customised `InputFormatReader` that sets the `isSplitable` property of the input as `false` .However this gives me the following error.

```
INFO mapred.MapTask: Record too large for in-memory buffer
```

The code I use to read data is

```
Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
                FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
                FSDataInputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = fs.open(file);


                    IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);

                    value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);

                }
```

Any ideas how to avoid `java heap space error` without splitting the input file ? Or in case I make `isSplitable` `true` how do I go about reading the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right - you load the whole file in memory. Unrelated to hadoop - you can not do it on Java and be sure that you have enough memory. 
I would suggest to define some resonable chunk and make it to be "a record"

Comment: I get wat you are talking about. I even tried coding it . But I started having issues with closing the input stream that would read from the source.Every time a chunk of the input was read and written into the mapper as a record , returning back to read the remaining wasn't possible. I would read a chunk of 1024 and set it as value for the record. `while(totalBytes < len){

    bytesRead =in.read(buf);
    }
totalBytes+=1024;      
} value.set(buf); `

Comment: Ok .. got thins sored to some extent . However I hv run into a new issue .. Please find that here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117719/downloading-files-from-ftp-to-local-using-java-makes-the-file-unreadable-encod)

Answer (score 1):

While a Map function is running hadoop collects output records in an in-memory buffer called MapOutputBuffer.

The total size of this in memory buffer is set by the io.sort.mb property and defaults to 100 MB.

Try increasing this property value in mapred-site.xml

Comment: Doesn't work .. I tried setting it via my code using 'conf.set' .. It did set the value to the one I specified but however it still runs into heap space error.

Comment: Doesn't work .. I tried setting it via my code using 'conf.set' .. It did set the value to the one I specified but however it still runs into heap space error